# Can anyone identify this connector?

Tags: connector

[image]

All I have been able to find is the image on google. This connector is used on my Mitsubishi and I would like to source replacements for some custom wiring. Wondering if anyone else has seen it or knows the manufacturer/series?

Comment: Your Mitsubishi what? Air conditioner? TV?

Comment: Maybe you have an old Mitsubishi zero WWII fighter plane: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjg3bGM_7jKAhVCXhQKHSAXB1MQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMitsubishi_A6M_Zero&psig=AFQjCNHLE0_3fzm7o6Vb4JL3y1_5bQExVA&ust=1453400000234937

Comment: @transistor he's tagged the question with 'automotive' so certainly not an AC or a TV or an old Mitsubishi zero WWII fighter plane.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't find this information yourself considering that you were able to find the image. The connector is Korea Electric Terminal Co. Ltd. type 7282-1020, part number MG641029.

Comment: @SurajBhawal Cars have ACs.

Answer (score 6):

**You asked**

> Wondering if anyone else has seen it or knows the manufacturer/series?

[Go here.](http://www.ket.com/kr/main.ket)

Enter the part number into the search field.

(Part Number - MG641029)

Your connector will pop up and you can add it to your cart for purchase.

Comment: you did a reverse image search?

Comment: No, I looked up the part number in the comments.

Comment: The ket website is configured strangely. If the link gets broken again, try a few different means to get the site to show up.